# Hub connection failures when using SignalR with Redis backplane

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, signalr

We have been successfully using SignalR for well over a year in our ASP.NET application. We recently deployed Redis to use as both a backplane for SignalR and for session management using the [ASP.NET Session State Provider for Azure Redis Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider). This worked well in our tests with only a few users and is usually working in production (~1200-1500 active sessions), but occasionally we are getting errors on the client side that indicate the user cannot connect to SignalR. These errors are confusing because they point to a simple JavaScript reference error, but we do not understand how anything could be wrong with the reference since it works greater than 99% of the time. I am able to reproduce this error on our test server by using Apache Jmeter to generate a large workload, choking the server's resources.

The error:

```
SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/js'></script>.
```

Our setup:

ASP.NET application running on IIS. Nested SignalR server that is started with an OWIN startup class. Redis ([Windows port by Microsoft](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases)) running on a different server.

References on page:

```
<script src="../js/SignalR/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Owin Startup class (I don't know if this is helpful, including just in case)

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Configuration;


[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRHubs.Startup))]
namespace SignalRHubs
{
    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            try
            {
                GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis("192.168.1.10", 6379, "", "SignalR");

                app.MapSignalR();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Log error with our logger
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `The error:` What line of code throws that error?

Comment: As far as I know, that error is generated by SignalR, so I have no way of knowing where it is generated. It occurs in the browser. I've only ever seen it when the JavaScript references were not correct, prior to deploying with Redis as the backplane.

Comment: What was the solution?